# What is a circularly sorted array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

I've seen it mentioned on the Internet. What is a 'circularly sorted array'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Usually it refers to an array in which the elements are sorted but may be rotated.  For example:

```
4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

The elements here, (`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`), are "in order," but they are rotated to the left by three.